# Magento : Edit Head Tag of Specific Page

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics, head

I'm trying to setup an **Analytics A/B** test on my **Magento**, on 2 landing pages (not homepage).

The problem is that, if I place Google Analytics Content Experiment code on every page of store, it re-directs automatically to one of landing pages no matter what.

If I'm not wrong, I must place code only on these 2 landing pages, but I don't have any idea on how to do this.

Anyone can kindly give me a hand?
Thanks!

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: It's just an Analytics script, which must be placed before the actual Analytics tracking.

<!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var
k='xxxxxxxxxxx-1',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;
...
valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
'" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})();
</script><script>utmx('url','A/B');</script>
<!-- End of Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->

If I put it in my theme's head.phtml it will show up on every page

Comment: on which page you want to display?

Comment: on 2 store category pages

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for that

GOto your layout file and write below code.

Below code is for category page and product view page

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="your_external_file">
            <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var k='xxxxxxxxxxx-1',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie; ... valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+ '" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})(); </script><script>utmx('url','A/B');</script>]]></text></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="your_external_file">
            <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var k='xxxxxxxxxxx-1',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie; ... valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+ '" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})(); </script><script>utmx('url','A/B');</script>]]></text></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="your_external_file">
            <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var k='xxxxxxxxxxx-1',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie; ... valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+ '" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})(); </script><script>utmx('url','A/B');</script>]]></text></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Or if you want this code is on particular category then goto `catalog->manage categories` select your category click on `custom Design` and put below code in `Custom Layout Update` textarea

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="your_external_file">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var k='xxxxxxxxxxx-1',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie; ... valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+ '" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})(); </script><script>utmx('url','A/B');</script>]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hi Murtuza, this last option works perfect, but I would need to put it at the beginning of the head tag, and not the end... is that possible?

Comment: @Luca `<block type="core/text" name="your_external_file" before='-'>` change this line only

Comment: @Luca if this answer solved your concern than mark as accepted so other users have same problem take benefit from this

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category')) // current category
{
    if(! Mage::registry('current_product')) // not product page
    {
        //Your Analytics script Here
    }
}
```